# change default metafont's mode/resolution (as when called directly from pdflatex)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, metafont, kpathsea

When I use a metafont font, pdflatex calls `mf` to generate the pk font files.
I would like to change the resolution at which the pk files are created.

If I'm correct, the call stack is:
`pdflatex` → `kpsewhich` → `mktexpk` → `mf-nowin`

As reported here http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Glyph-lookup , `kpsewhich` should call `mktexpk` to generate a missing font and this agrees with the fact that `mktexpk`  is not one of the shell_escape_commands in texmf.cnf.

To change the mode and resolution options that are sent to mf I tried to modify mktex.cnf, but with no luck (tried also config.ps just in case; I also ensured that kpsewhich was finding the modified files, not others).

My target is ljfzzz with 1200 dpi; does anyone know how to set these as default settings?

Also, how should I call kpsewhich so that it generates the pk files?
(of course, when the pk file does not already exists)

MWE - pdflatex the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shuffle}
\begin{document}
$\shuffle$
\end{document}
```

(eventually delete the file shuffle10.600pk if you already have it)

Comment: The simplest way is to add `\pdfpkmode{ljfzzz}\pdfpkresolution=1200` at the start of your document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to add

```
\pdfpkmode{ljfzzz}
\pdfpkresolution=1200
```

at the beginning of your document.

If you want to set this globally there are a few steps to follow.

1. Make a `mktex.cnf` file according to your needs

   ```
   : ${MT_FEATURES=appendonlydir:varfonts}
   : ${MODE=ljfzzz}
   : ${BDPI=1200}
   ```
2. Copy it as `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/mktex.cnf`
3. Make a copy of the default `pdftexconfig.tex` file in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.tex` and change the line

   ```
   \pdftexpkresolution=600
   ```

   to

   ```
   \pdftexpkresolution=1200
   ```
4. Save the modified file in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.tex`
5. Run `mktexlsr`
6. Run `fmtutil-sys --byengine pdftex`

All steps unfortunately unavoidable, because `pdftex` starts by default with `\pdfpkresolution=72`, so a suitable value for this parameter must be set in the format.

This is an area where improvements could be made. For instance, the default value for `\pdfpkresolution` could be set according to a `kpathsea` variable instead of `72`. This would avoid adding a value in `pdftexconfig.tex` and so just the change to `mktex.cnf` and setting the value in `texmf.cnf` would be necessary. So just steps 1, 2 and 5 would be needed.

Tested on a vanilla TeX Live on a GNU/Linux box. Note that you should have super user privileges and be careful that the super user shell path points to the correct TeX Live binaries.