# First use of mathbbm prints out unreadable

Tags: pdftex, mathbb

When applying \mathbbm to a letter for the first time in a document and then producing a PDF, the letter appears correct on the screen but is shaded away and almost unreadable on a printout from a printer. This only applies to the very first letter \mathbbm is applied to in a document. Has anyone had the same problem? Does anyone know how to fix it?

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{bbm}


\begin{document}
$$\mathbbm{P}[X]=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\mathbbm{N}$$
\end{document}
```

The P appears normal when the PDF is viewed on the screen but once the document is printed off, it is shaded. The N, however, prints out correctly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you post your code as `MWE`? It will helps to do a detailed analysis...

Comment: (1) Welcome, to TSE, (2) can you please provide some code that generates a document what when printed should give this. I've never heard of such a problem before.

Comment: The font used by `\mathbbm` is only available in bitmap form, so it will be jagged on high resolution printers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments, I've added an MWE to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the image of the output I get from your example, taken from a magnified view.

[image]

You can clearly see that the letters P and N from the `bbm` font are jagged, whereas the others characters show very cleanly.

The fonts used by the `bbm` package are only available as bitmaps. The package hasn't been maintained for 20 years.

Note that the P has “more chances” to be printed badly, because of the curve. To the contrary, N has mostly straight paths.

You may be able to reduce the amount of jagging by adding

```latex
\pdfpkmode{ljfzzz}
\pdfpkresolution=1200
```

at the very beginning of your document (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336216/4427). Resolution can also be made higher, but for your printer 1200 should suffice.

[image]

In my opinion it's better to switch to a different “blackboard bold” font.